Where does iTunes save iOS updates on Windows 11?
I searched the site and found this question about the location of iOS updates, but the most recent answer was for Windows 10. I am using Windows 11, and it seems the location is different for this OS. I have the following questions:

Where are the fully completed iOS updates stored on Windows 11?
Where are the temporary downloads stored on Windows 11?

The second question is particularly important to me because iTunes has been downloading iOS updates for more than 10 hours. I am worried that if the internet connection breaks, all the progress will be lost. Any clarification on this would be appreciated.

More than 10 hours? How slow is your internet connection? The latest iOS update was ~ 7.5GB in size.

@IconDaemon I don't think the issue is with the internet connection. Apple provides very limited bandwidth for updates outside of the US, which is likely causing the delay. I am trying to update a phone running iOS 14 to the latest version, and it has been very challenging.
iTunes is not helpful in this situation either. It doesn't display the update it is currently downloading or the progress, leading to a lot of uncertainty. It's no surprise that it has a user rating of 2.6 out of 5 as of now.
